# determining type of selected file in javascript in all browsers

Tags: javascript, file, browser

In an `<input type="file" >` element ,I am selecting a file of extension .srt and determining the type of the file using javascript.I tried this

```
var file=document.getElementById('fselect').files[0];
success = file.type =='application/x-subrip'? true : false;
console.log('selected a  file of type='+file.type);
console.log('selected a subtitle file='+success);
```

However,I get the expected results only in `chrome 18.0.1025.168`

```
selected a  file of type= application/x-subrip
selected a subtitle file= true
```

But in `firefox 12` with firebug installed,I get

```
selected a  file of type= 
selected a subtitle file= false
```

I am confused by this..how can I consistently determine the type of file in both browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5's File API. It is currently supported in every single modern browser including IE 9.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;                  // file list
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if(f.type){
            console.log(f.type); 
        }else{
            var match = f.name.match(/^.+(\.[^\.]+)$/);
            if(match) {
                console.log(match[1]);
            }else{
                console.log('no MIME type nor extension');
            } 
        }
    }
}

document
    .getElementById('files')
    .addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```
<input type="file" id="files">
```

**LIVE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/f2WmJ/

It *should* be the same across the browsers because it is a standard.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the browser does not recognize the `srt` file extension and thus does not know the MIME type, rather than a failure of the JavaScript to retrieve the MIME type from the browser.

Comment: @icktoofay - Maybe it is, but it is still better to use HTML5.

Comment: The code in the question accessed the `files` property on an `input` element, [which is defined in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-files). Thus, the code in the question was already using HTML5.

Comment: @icktoofay -  Updated code, you can test the part after the `.` to test if it is `.srt`.

Comment: @icktoofay - Then test it if it has an extension. If no, output `unknown`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" onChange="showExcelData(this)">

function showExcelData(event)
{
    var file=event.value;
    file=file.substr(file.lastIndexOf("/")+1,file.length);
    file=file.substr(file.lastIndexOf(".")+1,file.length);
    console.log(file);

    /* You Can Return the Data or Anything You Want to Do */
}
```